# Listing network interfaces and list of IP's attached to each of them CentOS7

Tags: bash, centos7

I know how to list Network interfaces:

```
ip ntable | grep dev | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/^.*dev //;/^lo/d'
```

and how to list ip's :

```
hostname -i
```

But Can't manage to list them nice way

Desired output would be:

```
IPv4:
Interface_1      IP_1, IP2
Interface_2      IP_4
Interface_3      IP_5
IPv6: 
Interface_1      IP1
```

Comment: Use `awk` to combine all the IPs for the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

A quick approach that gives you the output in format:

> Interface_1
>
> IPv4: xxxxxxxx IPv6: xxxxxxxx
>
> Interface_2
>
> IPv4: xxxxxxxx IPv6: xxxxxxxx

Would be:

```
for i in $(ip ntable | grep dev | sort -u | awk '{print $2}'); do echo $i; ifconfig $i | grep inet | sed -e 's/\<inet\>/IPv4:/g' | sed -e 's/\<inet6\>/IPv6:/g' | awk '{print $1$2}'; done
```

You can parse the output to have the format as you like.